# Hosted message bus like Pusher but big messages

Tags: messaging, pusher, real-time-data

Pusher is awesome but I want to try and throw some larger messages at it without chuncking. Does anyone know of a hosted service with similar features, including private channels, that offers bigger messaging (sub 2mb) is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Realtime.co and we do provide that feature. You can learn more about the technology at www.realtime.co, register for free at https://app.realtime.co/developers/getlicense (you can use your free account for any project you like - including commercial projects) and check out the documentation here: http://docs.xrtml.org/.

You can also find the APIs at http://www.xrtml.org/downloads and lots of cool code and examples at https://github.com/rtwworld. If there's anything you need help with or any questions that you may have, you can always reach me personally as I am the Developer Evangelist for Realtime.

I hope that helps and that you have lots of fun developing your project!